# Get a class (static) property from an instance

Tags: typescript

**Updated question:**

In a client-side app, I am implementing an event-handling system, similarly to how Redux works.
I define event types as subclasses of a custom `Event` class. All such subclasses have their own `type` static property.
I trigger an event by creating an instance of a subclass, and sending it to the main handler function.
In this main handler, I want to use `type` to decide which specific handler to call.

Since an event is an instance of an Event subclass, I use `event.constructor.type`.
It compiles and works fine, but the IDE complains: `Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Function'` (I also marked it in the code example).

Shall I just ignore the message, or is there a better way to access that static property from an instance?

```
type State = {};

class Event {
    public static type: string;
}

class MouseMoveEvent extends Event {
    public static type = "MouseMoveEvent";
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) {
        super();
    }
}

class KeypressEvent extends Event {
    public static type = "KeyPressEvent";
    constructor(public key: string) {
        super();
    }
}

function handleMouseMove(event: MouseMoveEvent, state: State): State {
    // return some new state
}

function handleKeyPress(event: KeyPressEvent, state: State): State {
    // return some new state
}

const handlerMap: { [type: string]: (event: Event, state: State) => State; } = {
    [MouseMoveEvent.type]: (event: Event, state: State) => handleMouseMove(event as MouseMoveEvent, state),
    [KeyPressEvent.type]: (event: Event, state: State) => handleKeyPress(event as KeyPressEvent, state)
    // etc.
};

// The main handler, it receives all triggered events, and decides which specific handler to call, based on the `type` property.
function handleEvent(event: Event, state: State): State {
    // the editor complains here
    return handlerMap[event.constructor.type](event, state);
}
```

**Original question:**

```
class BaseClass {
    public static type: string;
}

class SubClass1 extends BaseClass {
    public static type = "SubClass1";
}

class SubClass2 extends BaseClass {
    public static type = "SubClass2";
}

const map: {[type: string]: number} = {
    [SubClass1.type]: 1,
    [SubClass2.type]: 2
};

function getNumber(x: BaseClass): number {
    return map[x.constructor.type]; // complains here
}

const foo = new SubClass1();
console.log(getNumber(foo));
```

While this code compiles and works (console outputs "SubClass1"), the editor complains: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Function'.

I tried it in Intellij Idea and the Typescript playground (www.typescriptlang.org/play). Shall I just ignore the editor message, or is there a better way to access that static property from an instance?

Comment: Please include the line where the error originates from.

Comment: What is the goal of this code? Is it to get runtime introspection of the class type? If so you may want to use the Metadata api if this is intended for server-side code. Metadata introspection can lead to code not being tree shakable.

Comment: You're not returning the result of `handleMouseMove`/`handleKeyPress` from the mapped function.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a type for the `BaseClass` constructor:

```
interface BaseClassStatic {
    type: string;
    new (): BaseClass;
}
```

And then cast to it:

```
function getNumber(x: BaseClass): number {
    return map[(x.constructor as BaseClassStatic).type];
}
```